# batch size from data base reference

Tags: anylogic

i tried to get batch size values from database table in sequence, but getting errors in process.

i tried to set a condition to choose the size according to id parameter in my agent.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ccP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcy0P.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw8XQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This bit does not allow access to agents flowing through.

As suggested previously, it is easier to store the batch size within the agent as a parameter `p_BatchSizeToUse` (define it in the Source when the agent is created).

Then, simply set the batch size upfront in a block upstream of the Batch block using `myBatchBlock.set_batchSize(agent.p_BatchSizeToUse)`

HOWEVER: It is not logical to vary the batch size agent by agent. If the first agent has a batch size of 5 and the second has a batch size of 10, the first agent's batch size would not be considered as the 2nd takes over. You will not get the desired result with your setup, tbh.

Comment: thanks ben for your concern, i just want to batch every multiple agents arrivals toether in one batch thats my whole problem and i can't get it done

Comment: myBatchBlock.set_batchSize(agent.p_BatchSizeToUse) where to use it in source (before arrival)?

Comment: Create a new issue if that is the actual problem you struggle with (I know this is annoying but use SOF the way it should be used and you can gain a ton of tips very fast). Tips as before: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow